# Change textsize of summary of a preference

Tags: android, preferences

Can I somehow change the `Textsize` of the summary of an `EditTextPreference`?
I would like to do it in the `PreferenceFragment` and not in the xml-file.
I know I can access the `Preference` with `findPreference`.